# Styling tables in the preamble for the entire document

Tags: tables, pdftex

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the overall format of the tables included in a document (article or report) without applying commands in each table separately?

I found similar topics however the solutions are applied on each table separately. I would like to include something in the preamble that would a) format the tables in the entire document (for example, remove the column separating line, increase the space for the letters on each row, colour the text of the first row of the tables, ) and b) it will allow longer tables to be broken in two pages if it is needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Short answer: "No". Longer answer: latex is an open source macro language so you can redefine anything, so anything is possible (but if you redefine too much you probably break something else). If you narrowed your question down and made a small example document and asked just about one thing (eg defaulting the preamble, or defaulting the first row font,) then  more likely to get a usable answer. With the question stated in the generality as above I think the short answer is correct:-)

Comment: @Johannes_B oops you got your short answer in as I was typing:-)